# ros_desktop OS X Build Issue

Tags: rviz, catkin, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to build everything required to run rviz on my OS 10.8.3 machine. I followed the instructions here:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/MacPorts/Source

...except that I changed *ros_comm* to *desktop* in the *wstool* command. When I run the prescribed *cmake* command, I get this output:

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/groovy  -DSETUPTOOLS_DEB_LAYOUT=OFF
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: 
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
CMake Warning at catkin/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake:90 (message):
  nosetests not found, Python tests can not be run (try installing package
  'python-nose')
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  catkin/cmake/all.cmake:133 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (include)


-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/test_results
-- catkin 0.5.65
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 156 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - angles
-- ~~  - bond_core (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'bond_core' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/bond_core/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - common_msgs (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'common_msgs' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/common_msgs/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - console_bridge
-- ~~  - class_loader
-- ~~  - convex_decomposition
-- ~~  - cpp_common
-- ~~  - diagnostics (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'diagnostics' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/diagnostics/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - driver_common (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'driver_common' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/driver_common/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - genmsg
-- ~~  - gencpp
-- ~~  - genlisp
-- ~~  - genpy
-- ~~  - geometry (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'geometry' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/geometry/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - geometry_experimental (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'geometry_experimental' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/geometry_experimental/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - image_common (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'image_common' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/image_common/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - ivcon
-- ~~  - kdl (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'kdl' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/kdl/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - message_generation
-- ~~  - message_runtime
-- ~~  - mk
-- ~~  - nodelet_core (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'nodelet_core' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/nodelet_core/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - opencv2 (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - orocos_kdl
-- ~~  - orocos_kinematics_dynamics (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'orocos_kinematics_dynamics' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - python_orocos_kdl
-- ~~  - qt_dotgraph
-- ~~  - qt_gui
-- ~~  - qt_gui_app
-- ~~  - qt_gui_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - qt_gui_py_common
-- ~~  - ros (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_comm (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_tutorials (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rosbash
-- ~~  - rosboost_cfg
-- ~~  - rosbuild
-- ~~  - rosclean
-- ~~  - roscpp_traits
-- ~~  - roscreate
-- ~~  - rosgraph
-- ~~  - roslang
-- ~~  - roslaunch
-- ~~  - rosmake
-- ~~  - rosmaster
-- ~~  - rosmsg
-- ~~  - rospack
-- ~~  - roslib
-- ~~  - rosparam
-- ~~  - rospy
-- ~~  - rosservice
-- ~~  - rostime
-- ~~  - roscpp_serialization
-- ~~  - python_qt_binding
-- ~~  - rosunit
-- ~~  - rosconsole
-- ~~  - pluginlib
-- ~~  - qt_gui_cpp
-- ~~  - resource_retriever
-- ~~  - rosconsole_bridge
-- ~~  - rostest
-- ~~  - rqt_action
-- ~~  - rqt_bag
-- ~~  - rqt_bag_plugins
-- ~~  - rqt_common_plugins (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rqt_console
-- ~~  - rqt_dep
-- ~~  - rqt_graph
-- ~~  - rqt_gui
-- ~~  - rqt_logger_level
-- ~~  - rqt_msg
-- ~~  - rqt_plot
-- ~~  - rqt_publisher
-- ~~  - rqt_py_common
-- ~~  - rqt_py_console
-- ~~  - rqt_reconfigure
-- ~~  - rqt_service_caller
-- ~~  - rqt_shell
-- ~~  - rqt_srv
-- ~~  - rqt_topic
-- ~~  - rqt_web
-- ~~  - smclib
-- ~~  - std_msgs
-- ~~  - actionlib_msgs
-- ~~  - bond
-- ~~  - diagnostic_msgs
-- ~~  - geometry_msgs
-- ~~  - eigen_conversions
-- ~~  - kdl_conversions
-- ~~  - nav_msgs
-- ~~  - rosgraph_msgs
-- ~~  - bondpy
-- ~~  - diagnostic_common_diagnostics
-- ~~  - rqt_gui_py
-- ~~  - sensor_msgs
-- ~~  - camera_calibration_parsers
-- ~~  - cv_bridge
-- ~~  - image_geometry
-- ~~  - shape_msgs
-- ~~  - std_srvs
-- ~~  - stereo_msgs
-- ~~  - tf2_msgs
-- ~~  - trajectory_msgs
-- ~~  - urdfdom_headers
-- ~~  - srdfdom
-- ~~  - srdf
-- ~~  - urdfdom
-- ~~  - urdf_interface
-- ~~  - urdf_parser
-- ~~  - vision_opencv (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'vision_opencv' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/vision_opencv/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - visualization_msgs
-- ~~  - xmlrpcpp
-- ~~  - roscpp
-- ~~  - bondcpp
-- ~~  - collada_parser
-- ~~  - dynamic_reconfigure
-- ~~  - nodelet
-- ~~  - roscpp_tutorials
-- ~~  - rosout
-- ~~  - actionlib
-- ~~  - diagnostic_aggregator
-- ~~  - diagnostic_updater
-- ~~  - message_filters
-- ~~  - image_transport
-- ~~  - camera_info_manager
-- ~~  - polled_camera
-- ~~  - rosnode
-- ~~  - rospy_tutorials
-- ~~  - rostopic
-- ~~  - roswtf
-- ~~  - rqt_gui_cpp
-- ~~  - rqt_image_view
-- ~~  - self_test
-- ~~  - tf
-- ~~  - laser_geometry
-- ~~  - tf2
-- ~~  - tf2_ros
-- ~~  - tf2_geometry_msgs
-- ~~  - tf2_kdl
-- ~~  - tf2_tools
-- ~~  - tf_conversions
-- ~~  - timestamp_tools
-- ~~  - topic_tools
-- ~~  - rosbag
-- ~~  - diagnostic_analysis
-- ~~  - driver_base
-- ~~  - interactive_markers
-- ~~  - nodelet_topic_tools
-- ~~  - rqt_launch
-- ~~  - turtlesim
-- ~~  - urdf
-- ~~  - collada_urdf
-- ~~  - kdl_parser
-- ~~  - robot_model (metapackage)
WARNING: The metapackage 'robot_model' has no CMakeLists.txt. Please add one to the package source. You can use the following file: /Users/ayrton/ros_catkin_ws/src/build/catkin_generated/metapackages/robot_model/CMakeLists.txt
-- ~~  - robot_state_publisher
-- ~~  - rviz
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:88 (message):
  This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
  a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (catkin_workspace)
```

My questions are:

1. Is it the case that there are non-catkin ported packages in groovy?
2. If so, which ones? Can I exclude them from the build?
3. If I instead follow the tutorial exactly and only pull down ros_comm, what can I do to merge in only those packages that I need to build rviz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60797/ros_desktop-os-x-build-issue/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2013-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, the tutorial at http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/MacPorts/Source is likely way out-of-date. I don't know if anyone is maintaining those instructions.

Second, the error you are getting is because you have to use `catkin_make_isolated` instead of `catkin_make` because your workspace contains packages like `opencv` which are not catkin packages, but are required for building all of ROS from source. (therefore you cannot exclude any of those packages, except pcl*).

You should look at the Homebrew instructions and substitute in macports where ever you see fit instead.

You can replace `desktop` with `rviz` in the wstool url and you will get only the packages required for rviz.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2013-04-16**:
Excellent, thanks for all the info!